# bad pre-installed intent for .xml files?

Tags: android, html, http

I have two questions:

First, how common is it to find the Listen app 
(com.google.android.apps.listen) pre-installed? I have a stock T- 
Mobile G2 and it's installed by default for me, but I'm curious where 
else it's distributed?

Second, I've discovered this app contains an annoying default intent: 
any link to a file with a .xml extension, regardless of the mime type 
results in a context menu prompting the user to specify if they'd like 
to use the browser or the listen app to download the file. 
Unfortunately for me I've got a website with bunch of .xml files with 
text/html mime types. Any link to those files triggers the context 
menu, even though the content is only HTML.

Seems like an overly aggressive intent got set in the Listen app, but 
it's unclear if I have any recourse, aside from changing the file 
extensions. Does anyone have thoughts on workarounds?

Comment: I discovered recently there's a [Stack Exchange for droids](http://android.stackexchange.com/).  If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might try there.

Answer (score 1):

> Seems like an overly aggressive intent got set in the Listen app

I would agree. I haven't run into this yet, because I haven't played much with this scenario, but if true, it would be rather annoying.

> but it's unclear if I have any recourse, aside from changing the file extensions

You can root your phone and remove the Listen app.

Or, if the XML files are supposed to be delivered to your own app, use a more precise `<intent-filter>` (e.g., match the scheme, host, and path too), and you should trump Listen.

Beyond that, no, you would need to change your file extensions.